# How can I take input of two different data type using scanf() from same line?

Tags: c, string, input, scanf, format-specifiers

I have to take input like this in two different variables.

e.g.

```
I am an engineering student, 34.
```

string:- I am an engineering student.
int:- 34

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    
    char str[100];
    int age;
    scanf("%[^,],%d",str,&age);
    printf("str=%s\nage=%d",str,age);
    return 0;
}
```

`scanf` can set what character to terminate

Comment: `"%[^,]` lacks a width limt and is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359).  Consider `"%99[^,] ,%d"` and check `scanf()` return value.